# sql server check if ordering is met

Tags: sql-server

i'm trying to better task scheduler software monitoring by querying a table, with column events, contains steps of tasks scheduler log: task initiated, task stopped, task triggered manually, etc

now i know that if a specific order of events is met, that the task was executed fully successfully

say that the optimal order of events for a task is

- task started
- task processing
- job task finished

now if for a particular task, i have the following order of events:

- task started
- start triggered manually
- task processing job
- task finished

this order of event is not optimal, because event start triggered manually is not part of the optimal order of events - i want to flag this task

now if for a particular task, the following order of events occurr:

- task started
- task finished

this order of event is not optimal, because event task processing job is missing, i want to flag this task
The optimal order of event I get using the following query

```
   select t.events from 
    (SELECT distinct events FROM [jobmonitoring]) t
    ORDER BY (case when activity = 'task started' then 1
                  when activity = 'task processing job' then 2
                  when activity = 'task finished' then 3
                  else 4 end)
```

i'm stuck in flagging the tasks that do not follow this particular order of events
flagging must respect, these 3 events in that specific order

desired output would look something like

| task | flag |
| --- | --- |
| a | null |
| b | null |
| c | flagged |
| d | null |
| e | flagged |

tasks c and e do not follow optimal event ordering

table jobmonitoring, looks like this

| task | events | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c | task started | 28072022 1205 |
| c | job task finished | 28072022 1305 |
| e | task started | 28072021 1005 |
| e | job task finished | 28072021 1105 |
| e | task processing | 28072021 1205 |
| a | task started | 21072021 0905 |
| a | task processing | 21072021 1005 |
| a | job task finished | 21072021 1205 |

Comment: Table structures, sample data and desired output would go a long way to making this answerable. As it sits right now it is nearly impossible to understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: provided additional details

Comment: You have a,b,c,d,e in your desired output but it isn't in your sample data.

Comment: sorry for poor wuality of post, was not aware of db<>fiddle tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `ROW_NUMBER` then group by `task` and use conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  t.task,
  flag = CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.events END) <> 'task started'
                OR MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 2 THEN t.events END) <> 'task processing'
                OR MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 3 THEN t.events END) <> 'job task finished'
         THEN 'flagged' END
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.task ORDER BY t.timestamp)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY
  t.task;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3f4c514d8632c3cad4dd0981779acc3a)

Comment: wow works like a charm, sorry for the poor quality of the post. many thanks 5*

Comment: @dmartins Please mark the answer as such if it meets your goal. That is how the site is designed to work - marking helps people find actual, working answers when they are marked as such.